# component not getting added into the frame as expected

Tags: java, events, event-handling

i was studying  event handling and performed the following:

- Created a JFrame without any component in it
- i overridden  the keyPressed() method in such a way that whenever a key is pressed from the keyboard,A button should appear in the frame(by using add() and then calling repaint()).
  **Now the thing i want to ask is that at the time of key press from the keyboard,nothing was being added to the frame,however after pressing the key when i resized the frame WINDOW,the button came out from nowhere in the frame....**
  what's happening?

  ```
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import javax.swing.*;

   class MyFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener
   {
   private JButton bt=new JButton();
   MyFrame()
   {
   addKeyListener(this);  
   }
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
   {

  this.add(bt);
  repaint(); 
   }
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
   {

   }
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
   {

   }
      }


       public class MyClass    /*class containing the main method*/
      {

        public static void main(String args[])
    {
  MyFrame frm=new MyFrame();
  frm.setVisible(true);
  frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  }
   }
  ```

Comment: Do not use `repaint` on `JFrame`. Try `pack()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ,nothing was being added to the frame,

The component was added to the frame. The problem is it has a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint

> however after pressing the key when i resized the frame WINDOW,the button came out from nowwhere in the frame

The layout manager gets invoked and the component is given a size and location based on the rules of the layout manager. So now you see the component.

When you add a component to a visible GUI the code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `revalidate` after adding a component to the `JFrame`

```
this.add(bt);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

`revalidate` revalidates the component hierarchy to account for any new components that may have been added.

---

`KeyListeners` don't work well for Swing applications as `KeyEvents` require focus to work. 
This is why in Swing it is better to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which allow you to map an Action to a KeyStroke even when a component doesn't have focus.

Comment: thanks for it,and will you be kind enough to clarify the use of revalidate() and  why not to use keyListeners...:)